# Design of Experiments (DoE) in Python?

Tags: python, statistics

Is there any module or package available in Python for using [Design of Experiments (DoE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments) methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried [pyDOE](http://pythonhosted.org//pyDOE/)? It is great for constructing factorial designs, response surface designs, and more. You can find it on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyDOE).

Answer (score 1):

Try this new code base which takes a simple CSV file as input variable's range and generates the desired DOE in another CSV file. It is not a full package but collection of functions to use.

[Design-of-Experiment-Python](https://github.com/tirthajyoti/Design-of-experiment-Python)